# listing files in different directories which have same file naming format [R]

Tags: r, list, cbind

I want to cbind several files together using:

```
do.call("cbind",lapply(sample_list, FUN=function(files){read.table(files, header=TRUE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)}))
```

However, my sample_list files (eg, 1c.QC.dat) are in different directories.  But the directories follow the same pattern:

```
/home/Project1/Files/Sample_*/*.QC.dat
```

where * is the sample ID.

Is there a way to list these files easily?

Comment: You could `paste` the directory name together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first select our `Sample_*` directories.

```
main_dir <- '/home/Project1/Files/'
directories <- list.files(main_dir, pattern = '^Sample_')
directories <- Filter(function(x) file.info(file.path(main_dir, x))$isdir, directories)
```

We now have a character vector of directories beginning with `Sample_`. Now we can read in our data.frames:

```
dfs <- lapply(directories, function(subdir) {
  files <- list.files(path <- file.path(main_dir, subdir), pattern = '\\.QC\\.dat$')
  subdfs <- lapply(files, function(filename)
    read.table(file.path(path, filename), header=TRUE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  )
  do.call(rbind, subdfs)
})
```

Finally, we bind them into one giant dataframe:

```
dfs <- do.call(rbind, dfs) # Notice we used the same trick twice
```

A shorter but cleverer option is to use the `recursive = TRUE` parameter on `list.files`:

```
dfs <- do.call(rbind, lapply(
  list.files(path <- '/home/Project1/Files/',
             pattern = '^Sample_.*\\.QC\\.dat$', recursive = TRUE),
  function(filename)
    read.table(file.path(path, filename), header=TRUE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
))
```

Comment: I"ve tried the last solution which doesn't seem to work.  However is there a `{` missing in the second?

Comment: Oops! Not sure why that worked for me on the command line. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm probably missing something obvious but every solution creates `dfs` to equal `NULL`.

Comment: It seems `list.files` returns `character(0)` when reading the file names in the sib directory. Not sure what might be going on here...

Comment: And the extensions are `.QC.dat`?

Comment: A little more to it but not much: `*.QC.sample.specific.txt`

Comment: Try replacing all instances of `\\.QC\\.dat$` in the code samples above with `.txt$`